# Setting an NSScrollView uneditable - Xcode x86_64 architecture

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, editing, x86-64

I'm making an application for someone, and I need to make this NSTextView in an NSScrollView uneditable. Whatever I do, I just can't get anything to work. There is no editable or allow editing check box in Interface Builder for it, so I'll to do it programmatically. So far, I have tried the follow codes.

```
[TextView setEditable:NO];
[TextView setEditable:FALSE];
[TextView.editable = NO];
[TextView.editable = FALSE];
[TextView editingNotAllowed];
```

and I just can't get anything to work. If somebody could please help, that would be well appreciated! Also, I'm doing this under:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
}
```

Thanks for any help at all!

Comment: No editable checkbox in IB?  I see one.

Comment: Its not an NSTextView, its an "NSTextView in an NSScrollView".

Comment: So?  You can still select the NSTextView and set its attributes.

Comment: No, its not letting me do that. Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: If you click it once, you select the NSScrollView.  Click it again, and the NSTextView gets selected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at delegate methods to `NSTextView`? (specifically `NSTextDelegate`)

If you implement `textShouldBeginEditing:` and return NO, it shouldn't edit.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextDelegate/textShouldBeginEditing:

Comment: Where is your TextView instantiated?  Can you confirm if the delegate method is even being called?